Question about Random variable and Distribution
I recently started learning about random variables and distributions. I have the feeling that I do not really understand the topic.
I will state the definitons and examples I use and try to describe what I am unsure about.

Definition (random variable)
Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be
a probability space. A random variable $X$ is a function $X:\Omega
 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\forall a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ the
event $\{ \omega \in \Omega: X(w) \in (a,b]\} \in \mathcal{F}$.
We will always abbreviate  $\{ \omega \in \Omega: X(w) \in (a,b]\}$ to
{$X \in (a,b]$}
Definiton (Distribution of RV)
Let $S \subset \mathbb{R}$. The map
that assigns the set $S$ a Probability $\mathbb{P}(X \in S)$ is called
Distribution of $X$.

About the random variable:
I think I do understand the definition in a formal way. Although I do not see the reason for the name "random variable". So it's just a function defined on the sample space such that the preimage of $(a,b]$ is in $\mathcal{F}$.
Question 1: Why and how are random variables useful?
About the Distribution of a RV:
First thing that stands out is that we now use $S$ instead of the interval $(a,b]$.
Thus my Question 2: Can $S$ be an arbitrary subset of $\mathbb{R}$ or is it just a placeholder for $(a,b]$?

Example: Let $X$ be the outcome of a dice roll. Then the Distribution
of $X$ is: $\mathbb{P}(X \in S)=\frac{|S \cap \{1,...,6\}|}{6}$.

About the example:
In case of this example, the sample space $\Omega=\{\cdot,:,:\cdot,::,::\cdot,:::\}$ consists of all possible outcomes of the dice roll.
Then the random variable $X$, assigns the number of pips on the dice a (latin) number, i.e.
$\cdot \mapsto 1$
$: \mapsto 2$
$: \cdot \mapsto 3$
$:: \mapsto 4$
$:: \cdot \mapsto 5$
$::: \mapsto 6$
Something that one normally does intuitively.
What I do not understand is what $S$ should be in this case.
Would I need to guess, I'd say $S=(0,6]$.
But then $\mathbb{P}(X \in S)=1$, which does not make any sense.
I would be happy if someone could explain the above example in detail with regards to where the definitons are used, what value everything has.

Well, your text ought to define probability space prior to this.  For the die, you could take the sample space to be the obvious thing, namely ${1,2,3,4,5,6}$.  For cases in which uncountably many outcomes are possible, you need some machinery to make sense out of things, and for that you have $\sigma$ algebras, which should also be defined in your reference.  See, e.g., Probability Space

For intuition, I'd suggest starting with counting measures, as with your die.  Then look at how the general theory extends that to more complicated event spaces.

$S$ cannot be an arbitrary subset of $\mathbb R$, as there may be some subsets of $\mathbb R$ which are not measurable.  But it can be an element of the Borel sigma algebra generated from all the $(a,b]$ intervals;  ${1,2,3,4,5,6}$ is one such subset.  The reason for defining "random variable" this way is to allow you to say the result from rolling fair dice is a random variable, or that a random variable can have a normal distribution with mean $7$ and variance $4$, or many other useful things.

@Henry Okey. I didn't have measure theory up til now. Do you know how to calculate the distribution in the above example? (I am still a little bit confused on what to do with $S$)

If it is a fair die, i.e. has a uniform distribution on  ${1,2,3,4,5,6}$ with  $\mathbb P(X=1)= $ $\mathbb P(X=2)= $ $\mathbb P(X=3)= $ $\mathbb P(X=4)= $ $\mathbb P(X=5)= $ $\mathbb P(X=6)= $ $\frac16$, then you can say things like $\mathbb P(X\in {2,5}) = \frac13$ or  $\mathbb P(X\in (-8,3]) = \frac12$  or $\mathbb P(X\in {1,2,3,4,5,6}) = 1$.

You can look at it this way:
Given a random variable X on a probability space $(\Omega_1,\mathcal{F}_1,P)$, in your case you have $\Omega_1=\{*,**,***,****,*****,******\}$. The probability $P$ is the uniform probability, i.e. $P(\omega)=1/6$ and $\mathcal{F_1}=2^{\Omega_1}$.
Note that $X$ maps the elements of $\Omega_1$ to  $\Omega_2=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. Now that we have the space $\Omega_2$, we can consider the set containing all subsets of $\Omega_2$, and call it $\mathcal{F}_2$, i.e. $\mathcal{F}_2=2^{\Omega_2}$.
As a consequence we get a "new" sample space $(\Omega_2,\mathcal{F}_2)$. The distribution of the random variable $P_X$ is now defined as
$P_X(A):=P(X^{-1}(A))$ for every $A \in \mathcal{F}_2$, where $P$ is the probability measure from our original space $(\Omega_1,\mathcal{F}_1,P)$.
Since you seem confused about the "$S$" in your example, I tried not to use this letter. Instead of $S$ I used $A$. I hope this answers your question.
Especially $P_X$ is now a probability measure on $(\Omega_2,\mathcal{F_2})$, thus we can now consider probability questions on the space $(\Omega_2,\mathcal{F_2},P_X)$.
The reason to use random variables is to get "machinery" to translate some problem/question to a more abstract/convenient one. For example consider throwing two dice. You can ask questions like:
"What is the probability that the sum of the pips is odd/even?"
"What is the probability that at least of of the dice is a prime?"
And many other questions. The thing is that you can define $X$ to be "sum of the pips" or "is it a prime".

Thank you very much!
